# How can I write data in different sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to input information on a Excel file. My code creates a file with different sheet names.

Now I need to write in each column stuff like:

```vb
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

'Start a new workbook in Excel    
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

'Creating Columns with names 
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
oSheet.Range("A2").Value = Now
oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Category"
oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Correct"
oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Answer"
oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "Time"
```

This writes the information in the same sheet in the corresponding column, but how can I write in different sheets?

I generate the sheets with:

```
'Adding Sheets To the excel 
'oBook.Worksheets.add.Name = "Sounds"
'oBook.Worksheets.add.Name = "Colors"
'oBook.Worksheets.add.Name = "Animals"
'oBook.Worksheets.add.Name = "Forms"
```

So to clarify, I want to write the "Date", "Category", "correct", "answer", "Time" in each of the generated sheets, and not in one sheet.

Comment: Are you using VBA, VB.Net, or vbscript ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VBA as tagged:

```vb
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object, arrSheets, e

'Start a new workbook in Excel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

arrSheets = Array("Sounds", "Colors", "Animals", "Forms")

For Each e In arrSheets
    With oBook.Worksheets.Add()
        .Name = e
        .Range("A1").Value = "Date"
        .Range("A2").Value = Now
        .Range("B1").Value = "Category"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Correct"
        .Range("D1").Value = "Answer"
        .Range("E1").Value = "Time"
    End With
Next e
```

Comment: exactly VBA , thanks a lot gonna give it a try